# HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable in Azure server for rest services deployed

Tags: azure

I am facing 503 service unavailable issue since last 2 days on my server. It was working fine before weekend.

I am attaching the HTTPERR log file details below:

> 2016-03-20 17:03:36 223.24.10.10 60767 10.0.0.4 80 HTTP/1.1 GET /eddee/GetUserByUserId189 503 1 AppOffline DefaultAppPool
>   2016-03-20 17:03:51 223.24.10.10 36435 10.0.0.4 80 HTTP/1.1 GET /eddee/GetConfiguration 503 1 AppOffline DefaultAppPool
>   2016-03-20 17:04:05 223.24.10.10 58975 10.0.0.4 80 HTTP/1.1 GET /eddee/Pictures/268_VendorLogopic_1932016111550.png 503 1 AppOffline DefaultAppPool

Can someone please help me out with this?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Improved formatting and question title

Answer (score 2):

Your application (WebApp) seems to be offline (stopped). This happens very often with apps deployed on FREE or SHARED tiers, as there are limited resources. Scale your App Service Plan up (to Basic) to avoid this.

Comment: is this solution for any one ?

Comment: this was in 2016. Today there are other possible reasons for 503 (next to app service web app being stopped) - e.g. if you are running Containers and your app inside the container breaks, you will most likely see 50X error (not sure if it will be exactly 503, but will be 50X).

Comment: http5x error i am geeting in graph but not getting any detail

Answer (score -2):

503 error is simply shows that your service is inaccessible / stopped. 
Scale up your instance (Cloud Services) to get more resource for the service.

Hope that helps.